# How to troubleshoot blank phpinfo test page - PHP 7, Linux Mint 18.3?

Tags: php, linux, apache, ubuntu, failed-installation

I recently installed Linux Mint 18.3 Mate on a new PC.  It all works fine but I am unable to install PHP successfully as part a LAMP set-up (for use via localhost).

I installed LAMP via the terminal with

```
sudo apt-get install lamp-server^ -y
```

The Apache test (the "It works!" page) is successful.

The PHP test (a file that simply has `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` in it), though, produces a blank white page.  The file is called "testphp.php" and I attempt to access it at localhost/testphp.php.

I have checked several potential causes of the trouble:

- The phpinfo test file is in /var/www/html and I confirmed in the etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf file that this directory is the document root.
- I set display_errors = On in the /etc/php/7.0/apache2/php.ini file, but when I try the phpinfo test page, no errors appear.
- I checked the /var/log/apache2/access.log file to confirm that the phpinfo test page accesses are recorded by the system.  But no errors appear in the /var/log/apache2/error.log file on these access attempts.
- I confirmed that I have a current libapache2-mod-php by running:

  sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-php

  The terminal returned the message that it is already the newest version.
- I confirmed that PHP 7 (7.0.22-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) is running with `php -v` at the terminal.

What else should I check or do to troubleshoot this problem?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Does blank page mean HTTP status `500 Internal Server Error`? You can check that with any browser. Did you check PHP error logs as well? Does command-line PHP run?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: @Alvaro Gonzalez, the page is entirely blank with no "500 Internal Server Error" message.  In my question, I described how I checked the PHP error log (the location I listed is the same as that mentioned in another StackOverflow question thread: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5127838/where-does-php-store-the-error-log-php5-apache-fastcgi-cpanel)).

Comment: @jww, my question seems to fit the guidelines as it concerns "software tools commonly used by programmers."  When I did a web search on my topic, the most relevant and recent threads were on StackOverflow.  There are few such posts on the other sites you mentioned.  Even the "failed-installation" tag has been used here on hundreds of questions.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález, I haven't run PHP from the command line before.  How would I do it?

Comment: You only mention `/var/log/apache2/access.log` :-?. As about command-line, just type `php` in the terminal and hit enter (or, even better, `php -v`). Even though command-line settings do not need to be the same as Apache settings, it sometimes reveals installation problems that dump error messages, such as missing libraries.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález, as I mentioned in my question, I already ran `php -v` and showed a seemingly normal installation.  Here is the output: `PHP 7.0.22-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 (cli) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2017 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.22-0ubuntu0.16.04.1, Copyright (c) 1999-2017, by Zend Technologies`. What other logs should I check and where are they located?

Comment: Sorry, I overlooked that. PHP error log location is determined by the [`error_log` directive](http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-log).

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález, thank you for the further information.  The `error_log` directive was commented out in my php.ini.  I uncommented it and set a file name for the errors.  However, when I attempted to access `localhost/testphp.php`, no error was logged.